# Wraping rectangles with text around circle - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How to create **rectangles with text** around circle like the figure below using Illustrator.

[image]

Figure taken from here: https://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v13/n9/fig_tab/nmeth.3901_F1.html

Comment: Although the duplicate link above states "CS5" in its title, the methods are still essentially the same in more recent releases.

Comment: Thanks @Metis, however I'm also interested in the rectangles. I can make the text follow the circle, but I want the text to be inside a rectangle wrapping the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally prefer *not* to warp the text *and* the rectangles as one element. It *could* be done but it often means the text gets distorted somewhat. It's not overly noticeable at times, but there is a variation due to any warping.

The method I prefer is to set up the rectangles, then add Type on a Path.

For the rectangles, just create a **circle with a very thick stroke**.....

- `Object > Expand` (then you may need to remove the center spine depending upon what version of Illustrator you are using - some versions leave the spine, some don't. CC2017 requires the spine removal.)
- Draw rectangles to create the gaps in the circle.
- Select the circle and rectangles and Pathfinder Panel -> Minus Front to remove the the rectangles from the circle.
- Draw a new circle for the type to sit on
- Delete portions of this new circle that are outside the shapes
- Add the Type on a Path
- Select the type and rotate it around the circle's center while copying it (Option/alt key) to land on the other pieces
- Change text, and colors.

  [image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgT]